# Asking a question with lots of source code

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I've seen responses using [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/R7T3B/), where the code is broken up into html, css, javascript and the output.

Q: If I have a post that includes a lot of code, is is better to post it to an outside source, or simply paste it into my question in a code block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how many people think like I do, but I don't leave SO to view code.

1. I am hesitant to click on unknown links
2. If the user is posting so much code that they need to do it off site then I don't feel like digging for a needle in a haysack.
3. It requires me to look back and forth from the question and the code.  It makes it easy if they are closer together.

My guess is that you will have fewer people attempt to answer the question if you do this.

Comment: It's a good point about the outside sites but there are a few that we know are trustworthy, like github or pastebin or jsfiddle so sticking to those is ok. Anyways the idea is that he should be trying to reduce the code to the minimum necessary to show the problem that's being faced.

Comment: @drachenstern, I agree and Pekka had mentioned that in his answer, so I thought I would just focus on the answerer side.

Comment: I wanted to draw attention (shoulda gotten more sleep first) about sticking to well known sites so that we were comfortable clicking links. The second part was just for showing that I consider linking to code externally secondary to more explicit examples.

Answer (score 10):

The best thing to do is not to include lots of code in the first place. Try to isolate the very smallest piece that is necessary to illustrate the problem.

A JSFiddle is great for live demonstrations of stuff, but only posting a JSFiddle link is generally frowned upon.

If there is no way than to include the full code, I would post it on SO proper - SO's code formatting limits the height and adds scroll bars if it overflows.

Comment: Agreed.  Always reduce to the minimum code that shows the problem, and always include the code in the question.  But *also* including a link to a jsfiddle where people can see the problem in action makes my life easier as a potential answerer, and makes me more willing to spend some time on it.

Comment: Pekka or @bemace - What should we do when we don't know how much of something needs to be shown?  Is there a way to cause the scroll box to be shorter?  I'm trying to post something to superuser.com and I don't know how much of the information (a diff on two xml files) is necessary for potential answerers (and apparently "answerer" is a word).

Comment: @sage hmm, hard to tell without seeing the question in question... If in doubt, you can always show everything and reduce the amount as things progress.

Comment: I decided this merits discussion and I posted to meta.su, where it seems more applicable: [Is it... control the scrollbox height...?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1851/is-it-possible-to-control-the-scrollbox-height-for-pre-blocks).